# How do I store a JSON Value, with the rejson module in Redis using phpredis on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redis, phpredis

Normally when I json_encode and set a value in Redis it gets stored as a string. How do I store a value as [JSON](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/json/)

I've tried the following :

```
$redisCon = Redis::connection('default');

$data = $redisCon->executeRaw(['JSON.new', 'someKeyValue', '{"math":0}']);
```

but the response keep saying false and the data does not get saved.

I've got RedisJSON support on my redis instance, I'm running the redis/redis-stack-server:latest docker container to check this.

Comment: I think redis does not accept json/objects. Just convert your json object to string when saving and back to json when retrieving

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth, you should add this as an answer, as this is the correct response for OP's question.

Comment: Redis has support for JSON Objects with full-text indexing also https://redis.io/docs/data-types/json/

Comment: Ah I solved it :) $data = $redisCon->executeRaw(['JSON.SET', 'someKeyValue', '{"math":0}']);

Answer (score 0):

I manged to solve it, I was using the wrong command JSON.NEW, use JSON.SET instead and also put the path with $.

```
$data = $redisCon->executeRaw(['JSON.set', 'someKeyValue', '$', '{"math":0}']);
```